# Closed disk is simply connected

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I was trying to prove that the closed disk is simply connected. Although it seems to be obvious, I've got stuck on this question. I just would like to know if my proof is correct. The proof is what follows:

Let $D \subset R^{2}$ be the closed disk. We have that $D = B \, \cup \partial B$, where B is the open disk. It's known that the open disk is simply connected, because it is homeomorphic to $R^2$ which is simply connected.
We only need to show that $\partial B$, which is itself a loop, is homotopic to a point, let this point be the origin.

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \partial B$ be given by $f(x) = (cos x, sin x)$. We construct the following homotopy:

$$H(x,t) = (1-t)f(x)$$

We have then that $H(x,0)=f(x)$, $H(x,1)=0$ and since $(1-t)$ and $f(x)$ are continuous functions, $H(x,t)$ is countinuous as well.

Therefore $\partial B$ is null-homotopic.

And consequently $D$ is simply connected.

---

The only doubt I have is if it is possible to divide the total set into parts (in my problem B and $\partial B$), and check the different parts separately.

Thank you!

Comment: What if the open disk and the boundary don't have the same radius ?

Comment: The open disk is unitary. The boundary is, by definition, equals to $(\overline{R^{2} - B})\, \cap \overline{B}$. In fact, D = $\overline{B}$, where the overline indicates the closure of a set.

Comment: I don't see this playing any role in your proof.

Comment: The circle is not null homotopic.  I think you should do it all at once:  the closed disk is contractible.

Comment: Hint: Any convex space is contractible. Heck, any star-shaped domain is contractible.

Comment: Given a path $f$, consider the homotopy $H(x,t)=tf(x)$

Comment: Thank you everyone! I wasn't familiar with the concept of contractability.

Comment: Regarding your question of checking the parts separately: What would you do for a path $f : [0,1] \to B$ for which there exist $s,t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(s) \in \partial B$ and $f(t) \not\in \partial B$?